# Sum value of an array of structs in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, sum

I'm looking for some help on how to sum a value within an array of structs.

If I have a struct defined like this:

```
struct Item {
    let value : Float
    let name  : String
    let planDate : String
}
```

And then an array of these structs like this:

```
let dataArray = [Item(value:100, name:"apple", planDate:"2020-10-01"),
                 Item(value:200, name:"lemon", planDate:"2020-10-04"),
                 Item(value:300, name:"apple", planDate:"2020-10-04"),
                 Item(value:400, name:"apple", planDate:"2020-10-01")
]
```

How can I sum the `value` while grouping by the `name` and `planDate` as well as sorting by `name` and `planDate`?

Here's what I'd like to return:

```
let resultArray = [Item(value:500, name:"apple", planDate:"2020-10-01"),
                   Item(value:300, name:"apple", planDate:"2020-10-04"),
                   Item(value:200, name:"lemon", planDate:"2020-10-04")
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way (well, easy is in the eye of the beholder) is to make a dictionary that groups by a composite of your criteria, `name` and `planDate`. Now for each entry in the dictionary you've got an array of all the Items that go together! So just sum their values. Now make the dictionary back into an array and sort it.

```
let dataArray = [Item(value:100, name:"apple", planDate:"2020-10-01"),
                 Item(value:200, name:"lemon", planDate:"2020-10-04"),
                 Item(value:300, name:"apple", planDate:"2020-10-04"),
                 Item(value:400, name:"apple", planDate:"2020-10-01")
]
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: dataArray) { $0.name + $0.planDate }
let dict2 = dict.mapValues { (arr:[Item]) -> Item in
    let sum = arr.reduce(0) {
        $0 + $1.value
    }
    return Item(value:sum, name:arr[0].name, planDate:arr[0].planDate)
}
let dataArray2 = dict2.values.sorted { ($0.name, $0.planDate) < ($1.name, $1.planDate) }
print(dataArray2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I went with this approach as it was a little easier to read and get in my "newbie" Swift developer head.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach as well. First make your `Item` conform to `Equatable` and `Comparable`. Then you can reduce your sorted items, check if each item is equal to the last item of the result. If true increase the value otherwise append a new item to the result:

```
extension Item: Equatable, Comparable {
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        (lhs.name, lhs.planDate) == (rhs.name, rhs.planDate)
    }
    static func < (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        (lhs.name, lhs.planDate) < (rhs.name, rhs.planDate)
    }
}
```

---

```
let result: [Item] = items.sorted().reduce(into: []) { partial, item in
    if item == partial.last {
        partial[partial.endIndex-1].value += item.value
    } else {
        partial.append(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer another variant using `Dictionary(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`:

```
let dict = Dictionary(dataArray.map { ($0.name + $0.planDate, $0) },
      uniquingKeysWith: {           
         Item(value: $0.value + $1.value, name: $0.name, planDate: $0.planDate)
      })

let result = dict.values.sorted {($0.name, $0.planDate) < ($1.name, $1.planDate)}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's a solution that explicitly makes use of the fact that you want to use name&planDate as both group identifier, and sort key.

You can make use of the `Identifiable` protocol, and build a struct with name&planDate (structs are almost free in Swift):

```swift
extension Item: Identifiable {
    struct ID: Hashable, Comparable {
        let name: String
        let planDate: String
        
        static func < (lhs: Item.ID, rhs: Item.ID) -> Bool {
            (lhs.name, lhs.planDate) < (rhs.name, rhs.planDate)
        }
    }
    
    var id: ID { ID(name: name, planDate: planDate) }
    
    // this will come in handly later
    init(id: ID, value: Float) {
        self.init(value: value, name: id.name, planDate: id.planDate)
    }
}
```

Then you can destructure the `Item` struct by its identifier, accumulate the values, and restructure it back:

```swift
let valueGroups = dataArray
    .reduce(into: [:]) { groups, item in
        // here we destructure the Item into id and value, and accumulate the value
        groups[item.id, default: 0] += item.value
    }
    .sorted { $0.key < $1.key } // the key of the dictionary is the id, we sort by that

// and were we restructure it back
let result = valueGroups.map(Item.init(id:value:))
```

---

We can take it even further and refine the operations we need by extensing `Sequence`:

```swift
extension Sequence {
    
    /// returns an array made of the sorted elements by the given key path
    func sorted<T>(by keyPath: KeyPath<Element, T>) -> [Element] where T: Comparable {
        sorted { $0[keyPath: keyPath] < $1[keyPath: keyPath] }
    }
    
    /// Accumulates the values by the specified key
    func accumulated<K, T>(values: KeyPath<Element, T>,
                           by key: KeyPath<Element, K>) -> [K:T]
    where K: Hashable, T: AdditiveArithmetic {
        reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1[keyPath: key], default: T.zero] += $1[keyPath: values] }
    }
}
```

The two new additions, sort by a key path, and accumulate key paths by using another key, are independent enough to deserve function for they own, as they are generic enough to be reusable in other contexts.

The actual business logic becomes simple as

```swift
let result = dataArray
    .accumulated(values: \.value, by: \.id)
    .map(Item.init(id:value:))
    .sorted(by: \.id)
```

Even if this solution is more verbose than the other one, it has the following advantages:

- clear separation of concerns
- breaking the code into smaller units, which can be independently unit tested
- code reusability
- simple caller code, easy to understand and review